# ember - Controller action is only called by input field but not by button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to get started with ember and I am having a very strange problem. I use ember in the context of a rails-api app. The following code produces a quite unexpected result

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{input type="text" value=value action="doSomething"}}
  <button {{action doSomething }}>Button</button>
</script>
```

The action gets called when I enter something in the input field and press 'return' but not when I click the button. What makes this behaviour even more strange is that the same handlebar template works when I put it in JSFiddle. Because of that I suspect that the problem lies somewhere within my rails app.

My rails view looks like this:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => :all %>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
    <title>Title</title>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      {{input type="text" value=value action="doSomething"}}
      <button {{action doSomething }}>Button</button>
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

with the corresponding application.js

```
/*
*= require handlebars
*= require_self
*= require store
*= require routes
*= require_tree ./controllers
*= require_tree ./models
*= require_tree ./templates
*= require_tree ./views
*/

App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    doSomething: function() {
      alert('doSomething()');
    }
  }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

Maybe someone has an idea or maybe a hint how to debug this kind of problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the problem was but it disappeared after moving the inclusion of `ember` and `ember-data` from `index.html.erb` to `application.js`. I also added the gem `ember-rails`.

Answer (score 0):

In your rails view try to put your handlebars templates inside the `body` tag instead of `head`:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => :all %>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      {{input type="text" value=value action="doSomething"}}
      <button {{action doSomething }}>Button</button>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

### Update in response to your comment

To trace a click on the button you can register to the `click` event in your `IndexView` like this and put a break point to inspect further:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(event) {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not change anything. Any ideas how to trace the click event?

Comment: `click` did get triggered. I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem but event.currentTarget references the view instead of the button.